# Adding same package to Xcode workspace in multiple targets fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, package, swift-package-manager

I have Xcode workspace which has **Target_A** and **Target_B**.
I need to add THE SAME package to each target. The Package has xcframework "ABC.xcframework".

Target_A gets package url to **git_repo_A** which has Package.swift in it's root.
Target_B gets package url to **git_repo_A** which has Package.swift in it's root.

After adding to target the package in the Xcode UI, I get 2 errors:

```
multiple products named 'ABC' in: 'git_repo_A', 'git_repo_B'
multiple targets named 'ABC' in: 'git_repo_A', 'git_repo_B'
```

It seems Xcode want dev to use only one instance of the package, but I need to add it in each target separately without creating any dependency between the targets.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: the main issue here is that only _one_ version will be in the package cache every time (because how can it have 2 of them if they have the same name). So I don't think there's any way to solve it, try to rethink your strategy. For example: can you rename one of the packages? or can you have 2 branches for A and B (or even 2 repos).

Comment: Thanks @sfgblackwarkrts for your answer. I can't rename the package, since I should use the same one for both targets. I can take one of the targets out to from the workspace and work with project file. BUT this is not the optimum solution. Working in the same workspace is much more desired for time saving, sharing content and so on.